# Merge and populate tables

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have 2 tables in MS Access, that are updated externally each day (any tables I add will be deleted when the copy arrives in the morning):

- Current status of a customer
- All customer errors

The current status of a customer includes all customers in a particular process, and shows which status they are in today.  The "all customer errors" table shows the details of customers IF they had an error at some stage.  Both tables have some fields in common, but not everything (so a simple union isn't possible).

I need some help to do the following:

1. Join the tables and create a column stating the initial table they came from.  I realise I will have some duplicates.
2. Taking "current status of a customer" table, populate the missing data from "all customer errors"
3. create an extra column - "number of errors" where I count the number of times the customer appeared in the error table

Help!

My SQL skills are a bit basic, but improving each day :-)

Thanks

Kirstin

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must have a primary key and create an inner join. Use this formula in the SQL tab. You can then go into design view and use 'make table'. Simply select what data you want to appear.

```
  'SELECT column_name(s)
   FROM table1
   INNER JOIN table2
   ON table1.column_name=table2.column_name;'
```

When you have your new table you can update it to have new columns etc.

```
'UPDATE table_name
 SET column1=value1,column2=value2,...
 WHERE some_column=some_value;'
```